# How to cast main and sub `T` in generic sealed class and interface as type constraint?

Tags: kotlin

Here's a sealed class acting as an enum with associated values that constrains acceptable types to those implementing an interface holding a function that the sealed class should perform: `merge`

The problem is that at the function usage site, the pre-compiler claims a `Type mismatch` « Required: Nothing? Found: T & Any ».

Although it sounds 'natural' to have to cast `values` to `T.Collection` I have no idea how to say that in kotlin especially since the auto-completion doesn't propose anything on `T` and requests a `Nothing`?

```
interface MergeableCollection<Collection> {
    fun merge(with: Collection?)
}
sealed class CollectionType<T: MergeableCollection<*>> {
    // no data cases
    class none<T: MergeableCollection<*>>: CollectionType<T>()
    class standard<T: MergeableCollection<*>>: CollectionType<T>()
    // data case
    data class data<T: MergeableCollection<*>>(val values: T?): CollectionType<T>()

    fun <T: MergeableCollection<*>> finalCollection(standard: T): T? {
        if (this is none) { return null }
        if (this is data) {
            if (values != null) {
                standard.merge(with = values)  << *** `Type mismatch` ***
                return standard
            } else {
                return standard
            }
        } else {
            return standard
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really unclear what each of the types here are supposed to represent. Can you explain what everything represents and what `finalCollection` is supposed to do? Otherwise I don't see anything "natural" about this.

Comment: I see you mentioned "an enum with associated values" which sounds like something from Swift. Are you trying to translate some Swift code? If so, I recommend showing that code - it will probably make your question clearer.

Comment: Any way what it represents. It could be all types of data that 'collection` can hold.

Comment: The swift pending working perfectly but the big difference is that pure `enum` members (cases) stay in the scope of their `generic parent definition` that is not the same with `sealed class` and its members.

Comment: Neither of your comments answer any of my questions... Please illustrate what you mean by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: I have to agree with Sweeper here, please explain what you're trying to achieve. Maybe show examples of usages of your code and what result you would expect. Actually, it might be a good idea to provide the KDoc that you will write for this stuff - it will help us as much as it will help readers of this code.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a complete mess of the type hierarchy. What I *think* you're trying to do is this:

```
sealed interface MergeableCollection<T> {
  fun merge(with: MergeableCollection<T>): MergeableCollection<T>
}

class None<T> : MergeableCollection<T> {
  override fun merge(MergeableCollection<T> other) = other
}

class Standard<T>(val values: List<T>) : MergeableCollection<T> {
  // TODO this probably has a field containing some T's that's used in the merge implementation
}

// I'm not sure what the Colors specific implementation is for
```

This way, you don't need the `is` checks, the implementation classes provide them.

Comment: It's a good idea, but if I bunch the 'cases' in a generic sealed class it's because I need to specify dedicated applications at the function param site (so `paramN: CollectionType<CollectionN>).

But I should transpose your idea with a main class and inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

I simply solved it like that:
1- each sub class constrains their `MergeableCollection<>` to `T` rather than `*`
2- `values` is casted to `T?`

It works perfectly.
Thanks all to your question (especially @Jorn) that directed me toward the solution.

```
interface MergeableCollection<T> {
    fun merge(with: T?)
}
sealed class CollectionType<T: MergeableCollection<*>> {
    // no data cases
    class none<T: MergeableCollection<T>>: CollectionType<T>()
    class standard<T: MergeableCollection<T>>: CollectionType<T>()
    // data case
    data class data<T: MergeableCollection<T>>(val values: T?): CollectionType<T>()

    fun <T: MergeableCollection<T>> finalCollection(standard: T): T? {
        if (this is none) { return null }
        if (this is data) {
            if (values != null) {
                standard.merge(with = values as T?) // << CASTING
                return standard
            } else {
                return standard
            }
        } else {
            return standard
        }
    }
}
```